# DML Operations in BigQuery (Pricing, Daily limits and best practices)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

This is regarding DML operations in BigQuery (update and delete). We are facing the quota exceeded error after few queries. As we are planning to use"update and delete operation" largely in our script.

Can you help us knowing few things -

1. Can we increase the daily quota and will it come at an additional cost?
2. Checked support documents for processing cost for DML operations but didn't get the price. (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) what is the data processing cost of update and delete operations? Is it same as querying/extracting cost which is 5$/TB?
3. Would you recommend using "update and delete" operations frequently in big query or is there any other efficient and cost-effective way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

1. Paid customers (no longer in free trial) can request quota increases, this doesn’t have an additional cost. However, since quotas are important to guarantee resource availability, you have to provide a justification, a good reason why this is necessary for your business case.
2. You can find the DML pricing in the document you mentioned, in the [Data Manipulation Language section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#dml). To be verbatim, the pricing will be: “The sum of bytes in all the columns referenced from the tables scanned by the query, plus the sum of bytes for all columns in the updated table at the time the UPDATE/DELETE starts”.
3. I wouldn’t recommend frequent DML operations in BigQuery, those are not really efficient and are expensive. BigQuery is meant for long term storage and data analysis, you can see it as a Data Warehouse. For a transactional Database, consider other options as a traditional relational database (Cloud SQL or Spanner in GCP), or a No SQL database (in GCP Datastore or BigTable). The decision really depends on your data and your business case.